# Get last 3 instagram images posted in a place

Tags: php, api, instagram

I've been over the Instagram API for a long time, and couldn't find a way to get the last 3 instagram images posted in a specific place.

For example, a visitor search for "Patrick's Pub". The website will redirect him to the pub's page in my website, and there I will be able to display the last 3 instagram images posted in Patrick's Pub.

Is there any way to display these images? I thought about this URL:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=*LAT*&lng=*LNG*&access_token=*THETOKEN*
```

But there are 2 problems with this:
1. I can't find a way to convert *LAT* and *LNG* coordinates to a place (like the Patrick's bar)
2. If need an access token for this URL, it means the user need to log in to his instagram account, and it will not be suitable for the website, for just vieweing a place instagram photos.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a 3-step approach:

1. Instagram uses Facebook Places to tag a photo to places, you have to use `facebook graph API` to search for actual places at a location and get the `facebook_places_id`:

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={NAME}&type=place&center={LAT,LNG}&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&expires_in=5184000`

2. You then have to make a `Instagram location search API` call with the facebook_places_id to get the `instagram_location_id`:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?facebook_places_id={FACEBOOK_PLACES_ID}&access_token={ACCESS-TOKEN}`

https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/#get_locations_search

3. Use the instagram location id to get the recent photos from the place, using the `Instagram location media API`:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/{location-id}/media/recent?access_token={ACCESS-TOKEN}`

https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/#get_locations_media_recent

---

Here is an implementation of this search: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/places

Comment: Thank you very much, but in your first step I need to type LAT and LNG, and it's the same problem I had with the instagram API. I have no idea what the LAT and LNG are.

Comment: use google geocoder api to convert a city name to lat,lng https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/, thats what I do in gramfeed

Comment: Note that "the Instagram Legacy API is deprecated," ([Platform Changelog, Jun 29 2020](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/)). I recommend the [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/).